# Why isn't $ARGV[0] initialized by the file name I pass this perl one liner?

Tags: perl

I have a perl one liner that supposed to export each individual line in an xml file to it's own separate file with the name of the original file and then the line number within that file that it came from.

For instance, if the xml file is called "foo.xml" and it has 100 lines in it then I want to have a hundred files called, "foo_1.xml", "foo_2.xml", "foo_3.xml", etc.

I thought that the name of the file that I pass to the one liner would be available via ARGV, but it's not.  I'm getting a "uninitialized value in $ARGV[0]" error when I run this:

```
perl -nwe 'open (my $FH, ">", "$ARGV[0]_$.\.xml"); print $FH $_;close $FH;' foo.xml
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Also seeing this problem in a script. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When using the magic [`<>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) filehandle (which you're doing implicitly with the `-n` option), Perl shifts the filenames out of [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARGV) as it opens them.  (This is mentioned in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators).)  You need to use the plain scalar [`$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV), which contains the filename currently being read from:

```
perl -nwe 'open (my $FH, ">", "${ARGV}_$.\.xml"); print $FH $_;close $FH;' foo.xml
```

(The braces are necessary because `$ARGV_` is a legal name for a variable.)

Comment: Works for me. I got a directory full of files with individual lines! I'll be more careful in the future...

Comment: @sehe, did you pass it the name of an existing file with content?  Perl will execute `print $ARGV` for each line it reads.  If it doesn't read any lines, it won't print anything.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that.

Comment: Thx for the hints. I don't really like the behaviour, but I guess I understand how perl would 'ignore' the empty file I had - indeed - created. +1

Answer (score 3):

cjm has the correct answer. However, it will create files such as `foo.xml_1.xml`. You asked for `foo_1.xml`, etc.

```
perl -nwe '
my ($file) = $ARGV =~ /(\w+)/;
open my $fh, ">", $file . "_$..xml" or die $!;
print $fh $_;
' foo.xml
```

Comment: Good point.  I overlooked that part of his requirements, mainly because his original code would have had the same problem, if it had worked.  His main problem was just finding the filename, not transforming it.